# Meshroom: how to access the final camera parameters?

Tags: photogrammetry, meshroom

I am trying to write a script which loads the camera parameters from Meshroom and imports them into a CAD program. My first understanding was that these parameters (position, rotation matrix, focal length etc.) are contained in the JSON-file *cameras.sfm* in the *StructureFromMotion*-subdirectory.

After importing these parameters into Rhino3D and comparing the resulting views onto the 3D-mesh with the undistorted photographs in the PrepareDenseScene-directory, I find surprising large discrepancies. The mesh which was the result of the run was good, so I think that the deviation is because of the parameters in *cameras.sfm* being not the final ones. This assumption is also supported by the fact that the file only contains the focal length as read from the input images' EXIF information and no refined values. So my question is:

**How can I access the final camera parameters from the output of Meshroom?**

Knowing this would help me a lot for re-building a photogrammetry/CAD pipeline I had previously implemented for VisualSFM + CMPMVS.

Many thanks!

*EDIT: As this is my first post, I am not able to create a new tag for Meshroom. Perhaps this could be added by someone else? Thanks!*